# Custom sibling angle for child nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

As I explored the TikZ manual and available examples; the position of child nodes are defined within the parent node. This means that all child nodes spread on the same radius from the parent with constant angle intervals.

How to define the `level dsiatance` and `sibling angle` individually for each child node?

```
\node[ball color=red,circle] (parent) at (5,5) {Parent}
    [level distance=4cm,sibling angle=30,clockwise from=0]
    child {node[rectangle,fill=red,color=white]
    {e.g. 2cm from parent at angle 0}}
    child {node[rectangle,fill=red,color=white]
    {e.g. 5cm from parent at angle 20}}
    child {node[rectangle,fill=red,color=white]
    {e.g. 3cm from parent at angle 60}};
```

Instead of constant distance from parent and equal angle between child nodes defined in

```
[level distance=4cm,sibling angle=30,clockwise from=0]
```

How to define a custom (independent) value for each child?

Comment: Can you post the "full" code? I mean, adding the preamble and the closing tags.

Comment: As Alenanno said, it would be good if you could always post full examples, including the `\documentclass` and the necessary libraries. It seems like a trivial thing for examples like these, but if you already include the necessary lines, it saves everyone else the work of having to add them themselves (and wondering why the example doesn't compile, until they figure out that the `trees` library needs to be loaded).

Comment: @Jake you're quite right! I will keep it in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the `level distance` and `sibling angle` options to the `child` keywords:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ball color=red,circle] (parent) at (5,5) {Parent}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child [level distance=2cm] {node[rectangle,fill=red]
    {A}}
    child [level distance=4cm, sibling angle=20] {node[rectangle,fill=red]
    {B}}
    child [level distance=3cm, sibling angle=30] {node[rectangle,fill=red]
    {C}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```